# How to split sentences in an array

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, text-processing, text-parsing

I have a string `s` which stores a very long sentence and I want to copy the content of `s` to an array `C` with each cell storing a sentence each. The following is my code which is not giving me any output, but the dimension of the cell:

```
while(i<6)
  C(i)=s;
  end
```

This is how I get as output when I print `C`:

```
C=
[1x76 char]
```

Can somebody please help me.

Comment: can you give an example ?

Comment: I want each cell to store a sentence.

Comment: example first cell store the sentence:The Moon is the only natural satellite of the Earth and the fifth largest moon in the Solar System.second cell store sentence:Among satellites with known densities, the Moon is the second densest, after Io, a satellite of Jupiter.

Comment: do you means very long sentence is combination of sentence. e.g "this is first. This is second." and you want it as two cell in array ?

Comment: yes exactly.please help me to find answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose Long string is:

```
longString = "This is first cell. This is second cell. this is third cell".
```

Now since `.` is delimiter here means it is acting as separator for sentences. so you can loop through `longString` character wise and whenever you encounter a `.` you just increase Array index count and keep storing in this Array index until you find another `.`

here is sudo code:

```
array[];
index = 0;
loop through(longString) character wise
{
if(currentChar equals  to '.')
{
index++;
}
else
{
array[index] = currentChanracter;
}
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Another job for [`strsplit`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strsplit.html):

```
>> sentences = 'This is the first one. Then here is a second. Yet another here.';
>> C = strsplit(sentences,'. ')
C = 
    'This is the first one'    'Then here is a second'    'Yet another here.'
```

We are specifying a period followed by a space as the delimiter. Change this as needed.